# Multitheading spring kafka consumer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Есть топик в kafka c одной партицией. Обработка одного сообщения из топика занимает продолжительное время. Можно ли написать многопоточный spring kafka consumer, чтобы успевать обрабатывать все данные, поступающие в топик? Либо подскажите другой способ для ускорения consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Сперва увеличьте количество партиций, например, до 4 или 8.

Затем используйте одновременно несколько консьюмеров, которые параллельно будут читать из нескольких партиций. Можно воспользоваться [`ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_concurrentmessagelistenercontainer). Внутри он будет использовать несколько `KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, их количество задается настройкой `concurrency`. Все партиции будут распределены между созданными обработчиками. В пределах одной партиции сообщения будут обработаны последовательно.